# How to specify the full path to latest cmake version when I use ccmake to configure my installation build

Tags: cmake, centos, geant4

I am preparing to install GATE on my CentOS 7, I have everhting done except Geant4. When I try to build the installation file and configure it with ccmake, like this

```
ccmake ../geant4.10.05.p01
...
Make Error at CMakeLists.txt:24 (cmake_minimum_required):
CMake 3.3 or higher is required.  You are running version 2.8.12.2
```

It always show that CMake version is 2.8.12.2 but not the latest version 3.15.3 I have installed. Does anyone can help? I will really appreciate any quick respond!

Comment: "How to specify the full path to latest cmake version when I use ccmake" - Just use `/path/to/ccmake` instead of plain `ccmake` when call it. Or add directory with CMake binaries to the `PATH` variable before the standard ones.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi, thank you for your respond. It looks like there is no ```ccmake``` binaries in the new cmake I installed, so could you explain second way more specificly? Like how to add directory of new CMake binaries to the ```PATH```? Appreciate your respond again!

Comment: If you don't have `ccmake` for the new CMake installation, then you cannot use it. However, you still may use `cmake` executable (either using its full path, or after adding to `PATH`). "Like how to add directory of new CMake binaries to the PATH?" - See https://superuser.com/questions/488173/how-can-i-edit-the-path-on-linux or google for other questions about PATH variable in Linux.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi, is ```ccmake``` come with cmake? Or I have to download it seperately? I notice that the ccmake in my centOS 7 system is installed with original cmake package.

Comment: `ccmake` is a part of CMake, but when build CMake from source you probably need to specify some additional options for build `ccmake` too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you so much! I get it, really helpful!!